# Apache Beam, BigQueryIO, writeTableRows() vs write()

Tags: java, google-bigquery, gson, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

how to choose these 2 write functions when using BigQueryIO.

Have found the
[official doc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.8.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html#:%7E:text=It%20is%20recommended%20to%20instead%20use%20write()%20with%20BigQueryIO.Write.withFormatFunction(SerializableFunction).)
here mentioning `writeTableRows()` is not recommended, but don't see why.

1. I can use `gson` to serialize my Java POJO to `TableRow` and write with `writeTableRows()` directly
2. I need to manually set the `TableRow` object if I use `write()`

Questions:

1. What's the reason to prefer `write()` and
2. do these 2 options have much performance difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR

These two options are equivalent, and have the same underlying implementation. Do not worry too much about the recommendation.

My advice:

- Try to format your data within `write` using the Format function.
- If you can't do that, then don't worry too much, and use `writeTableRows`

#### Detailed explanation

The difference is that `write` runs a formatting function, and for `writeTableRows` the formatting function is simply an identity.

I believe `write` is recommended over `writeTableRows` because `TableRow` objects are serialized with JSON. JSON is a very inefficient serialization format.

`write` realizes the conversion to `TableRow` right before sending the data to BigQuery, and `writeTableRows` converts the data, and then passes it around in a few transforms before writing to BigQuery - this means that serialization costs may be higher for `writeTableRows`.

Does that make sense? Thanks!

#### Explanation with *too many* details

The 'recommended' word in Javadoc was added in [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4694). I've asked why - we should hopefully get a response for it : )

Comment: They've replied "writeTableRows is often more expensive because it relies on json objects." as you suggested in your answer.

Comment: makes sense. If your rows are very wide (many columns), then the JSON inefficiency is worse - but if your rows are not huge, then it may be mostly fine - still though, it's better to use the format function

Comment: if the answer is appropriate, you can pick it as answering your question : )