# How to manage 'row too large' error during streaming inserts to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, insert, quota

I'm working on a Dataflow pipeline which uses BigQuery streaming inserts to load the data from Pub/Sub topic to the tables. The code snippet of the insertion is as follows:

```
    BigQueryIO
      .writeTableRows()
      .withoutValidation()
      .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
          .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
      .withExtendedErrorInfo()
      .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
      .to(table_id);
```

From time to time I can see the error during insertion **'row too large'** and as I understand that happens because the created table row exceeds the limit of 10MB.
Is there any way to increase this quota to be able to load such data? Is there any other approach I can use to overcome this issue?
Thank you

I was thinking about usage of Storage Write Api but seems like it has the same limit as Streaming Inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, instead of using `writeTableRows`, you can test with `write` to have better performance regarding serialization of large objects.

`writeTableRows` uses Json serialization and it’s not efficient.

For the limitation of 10MB, unless I am mistaken, you can’t increase this quota and you are right, this limitation is the same for `STREAMING_INSERT` and `STORAGE_WRITE_API` insertion methods.

However the `FILE_LOAD` doesn’t have this limitation and you can try with this method to solve your issue.

You can check these 2 Stackoverflow topics to have some explanations for this problem :

[writetablerows-vs-write-beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037635/apache-beam-bigqueryio-writetablerows-vs-write)

[size-limit-streaming-insert-beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74054690/request-size-error-while-inserting-record-to-bigquery-using-streaming-insert-bea)